# Neither Selenium or Beautiful soup showing full html source?

Tags: python, html, selenium, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I tried using beautiful soup to parse a website, however when I printed "page_soup" I would only get a portion of the HTML, the beginning portion of the code, which has the info I need, was omitted. No one answered my question. After doing some research I tried using Selenium to access the full HTML, however I got the same results. Below are both of my attempts with selenium and beautiful soup. When I try and print the html it starts off in the middle of the source code, skipping the doctype, lang etc initial statements.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
browser = webdriver.Chrome( executable_path= "/usr/local/bin/chromedriver")
browser.get('https://coronavirusbellcurve.com/')
html = browser.page_source
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
print(soup)
```

```
import bs4
import urllib
from urllib.request import  urlopen as uReq
from urllib.request import Request, urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
htmlPage = urlopen(pageRequest).read()
page_soup = soup(htmlPage, 'html.parser')
print(page_soup)
```

Comment: What info do you need?

Comment: I'm trying to access the numbers at the top of the page regarding US Covid statistics. However, it seems that both Selenium and BS are only parsing the source after the relevant statements.

Comment: BeautifulSoup doesn't do the request, urllib does

Comment: My question is more regarding the fact that I want to be able to access the full html source using BS or Selenium, and when I try and print out what SHOULD be the full source, I'm only getting part of it, and I'd like to know how to fix that. My understanding is that the code I have written should be printing out the full source? @ggorlen

Comment: So how do I make urllib correctly print out the entirety of the source code instead of only a part of it? @User

Comment: Your code does seem to give the whole source. What makes you think it doesn't? These are massive files and your console may be cutting off the top. Write to file instead of printing and inspect it from there. `soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(requests.get("https://coronavirusbellcurve.com").text, "lxml"); print(soup.find(class_="table-responsive-xl"))` gives me the table and I'm seeing the whole HTML for both request code samples.

Comment: the first line of the printed source for me is "th scope = col" whereas when I inspect the source on the page the first line is "doctype html" @ggorlen

Comment: Why are you running `print(page_soup)` instead of `print(htmlPage)` - there's no reason to parse it if you're just printing it

Comment: Is that cutoff you mention from a file you wrote or from looking at the console? `with open("page.html", "w+") as f: f.write(html)` then look at it. Skip BeautifulSoup as @User says. Adding an extra layer of indirection only complicates the problem.

Comment: I tried print(htmlPage) and still got the same result, source truncated in the same manner. @User

Comment: The cutoff is what I see when the print statement outputs into the terminal, Im not reading into a file or anything. And I'm not too sure how to use the code you mentioned or what it does? Apologies as I'm a noob. @ggorlen

Comment: That's OK. Consoles often have limits of how much they can print. Likely, the page is so large that it's overflowing the console. So, if you write it to file using the above code and look at it in a text editor, you'll see the whole picture. As long as you're printing it, you're in a situation where your console configuration might be limiting what you see. You can also `print(html[:1000])` to just print the first 1000 characters in the string.

Comment: Ah the print[:1000] showed me the expected output. So it was because my console could only handle so much at a time, got it. Here I was going crazy because I thought my packages/modules weren't reading correctly. Thanks! @ggorlen

Answer (score 0):

The requests module seems to be returning the numbers in the first table on the page assuming you are referring to US Totals.

```
import requests
r = requests.get('https://coronavirusbellcurve.com/').content
print(r)
```